# How to handle non-existing / dynamically created method?

Tags: php, oop

Let's assume I have dynamically created object that maps a database table's row. At the time of writing my code, I have no idea about table's columns. So what I store in fields are database connection, table name and primary key. And I want to create a method to receive fields, but instead of:

```
$field_value = $row_object->get_field("weight");
```

I want the code using my object to look like that:

```
$field_value = $row_object->get_field_weight(); //where weight is column name in db
```

I cannot know what exact names, like get_field_weight(), will be needed when I'm coding.
How can I implement this?

Comment: I really hope it's actually a duplicate of a question answered long ago, but I cannot find the answer, neither with built-in search nor using google.

Comment: How about [`__call($method, $args)`](http://php.net/__call) ?

Comment: Just try with `->getWeight()`. These are called magic methods.

Comment: Oh, right, thanks. I was sure it can be done, but it didn't occurred to me to search under "magic" and "overloading" keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`__call()`](http://php.net/__call) magic method:

```
class MyMapper{

    public function __call($method, $args){
        $parts = explode('_', $method);

        $field = array_pop($parts);

        if(!array_key_exists($field, $this->fields)){
            throw new NoSuchFieldException();
        }

       return $this->fields[$field];
    }
}
```

You might also use this for "set" operations, with some further improvement.